# Kotlin Firebase onFailureListener null exception

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update email of user in my android app. And everything works fine if the new email is available. When it isn't - onFailureListener is calling. But when I am trying to get the exception from this listener it is null and I can't get type of this exception. Why? Code below.

```
private fun reauthenticateAndUpdateEmail(password: String, newEmail: String){
    val credentials = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(auth.currentUser!!.email!!, password)
    auth.currentUser!!.reauthenticate(credentials).addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<Void> {
        override fun onComplete(p0: Task<Void>) {
            if (p0.isSuccessful) {
                auth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(newEmail).addOnSuccessListener {
                    interractor.emailChanged()
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    interractor.emailChanged(false, handleException(p0.exception))
                }
            } else interractor.emailChanged(false, handleException(p0.exception))
        }
    })
}

private fun handleException(exception: Exception?): String{
    //exception is null
    when(exception){
        is FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException -> return "E-mail address is not available"
        is FirebaseNetworkException -> return "No network"
        else -> return "Try again later."
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    interractor.emailChanged(false, handleException(p0.exception))
                }
```

with

```
.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    interractor.emailChanged(false, handleException(exception))
                }
```

You could also safeguard your handleException method:
Replace

```
    when(exception){
        is FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException -> return "E-mail address is not available"
        is FirebaseNetworkException -> return "No network"
        else -> return "Try again later."
    }
```

with

```
    exception?.let {
          when(it){
             is FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException -> return "E-mail address is not available"
             is FirebaseNetworkException -> return "No network"
             else -> return "Try again later."
          }
    }
return "Unknown error"
```

Comment: Replacing `p0.exception` to `exception` worked. Thanks a lot.